# Local Java Project jars aren't added to Maven built war - Eclipse 3.6 Helios

Tags: java, eclipse, m2eclipse, eclipse-3.6

In Helios, the old "EE Module Dependencies" was replaced with "Deployment Assembly" but it still does the same thing, allows for the addition of external projects, in this case, a pure Java Project.

This all works fine locally, but when I have Maven build the war for deployment, a jar is not added for the local java project. The project is not in Maven, but I have turned off the "resolve workspace dependencies" and in Eclipse 3.5, this would allow me to add the projects as described above, and have the jar's show up in the WEB-INF/lib folder.

Any ideas why this isn't working anymore?

Comment: When you say 'have maven build the war', are you running maven from within Eclipse, or from the command line?

Comment: from within eclipse, with run configuration-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Eclipse 3.7 (Indigo) m2eclipse was renewed and renamed but the behavior of the war plugin did not change imo:

Simply open your pom.xml and check the dependencies section. Your java project should not be "optional" and should not be a "provided" dependency. The behavior of the war plugin is described [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/war-manifest-guide.html). You can activate "resolve workspace dependencies" but your "plain" Java project should have a pom as well. If the maven build of your war fails (double check that) you should invoke "install" on your other project (or you can [install a jar for it manually](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html) if you don't want to make a pom.xml for it).

Comment: ok, so you're saying that basically, there is no way to get those external dependencies included, unless there is some way maven can know about them. Specified a module dependency in eclipse is not enough, and i can no longer get by without either adding a pom or manually installing those jars in my repo? that right?

Comment: Um, well, I'm not sure I understood you. If you build your war with maven (as runtarget) it takes only your pom.xml into account. So, yes, if you want the standalone maven to include a jar you need a dependency section in the pom.xml for it. That did not change.

Comment: i seem to recall that eclipse could put the jars directly in the web-inf lib, so they'd end up in the final package. maybe i's just trippin. ill try the manual install route, thanks-

Answer (score 0):

you may use a pom for **aggregation**. To see aggregation in action, just have a look at the [Maven](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/maven/maven-3/trunk/pom.xml?view=markup) or [Maven Core Plugins](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/maven/plugins/trunk/pom.xml?view=markup) base POM's.